# Failed to create task or type testng

Tags: ant

I am trying to run my testng project created in eclipse through ant. Getting below error:

Failed to create task or type testng. Name is undefined... here is the snippet:

```
    <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="suite">   
        <xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="testng.xml"/>
    </testng>
</target>
```

I also tried to add testng task but then nothing happens.

Please help!...

Answer (score 0):

You can find more around here: http://testng.org/doc/ant.html

Basically, you need to have a taskdef tag like:

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="path/to/testng.jar"/>
```

The testng task you wrote appears to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the TestNG tasks to Ant

```
 <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${extralib.dir}/testng5.13.1.jar" />
```